# html table space between cells but not from left and right table border

Tags: html, css, html-table, border-spacing

In my html I have a table with border-spacing set to 2px. Is it possible to remove that space between the first column and the left border of my table? And of course do the same on the last cell and the right border of table? Here is my html and css

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed ;
    width:100%;
    min-width:1024px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border-spacing:2px; 
}
```

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style='background-color:#f63; border-left:none;'>
   cell1
  </td>
  <td style='background-color:#f93;'>
   cell2
  </td>
  <td style='background-color:#f33; border-right:none;'>
   cell3
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add the following at the top of your stylesheet to remove a spacing:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then add `width:  100%;` to the table-selector, this will spread your columns, so there will no white space remain at the borders.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, what is table-selector?

Comment: Lukas means the CSS that you're using to target your table. So if this whole thing were wrapped in a <div id="mytable"> element, then your selector would be `#mytable table`

Answer (score 0):

Lukas is right.

```
/* This will remove all spacings from your page */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```